# ASp.net Button on jqueryui Dialog causes all from data to reset. UsesubmitBehavior=False, and databind in (!ispostback)

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, jquery-ui-dialog

So I've been struggling with this for a couple days now. I have a login page, that checks if the user is logging in for the first time, and if so, it shows a jqueryui Dialog box asking the user to pick their security questions. The Dialog is simple, three dropdowns, three text boxes, and a continue and cancel button. The dialog is displaying find, and when you click continue, the data is saved to the database, but it only saves the default values of the dropdownlists, and it doesnt save the text from the text boxes. It seems to me like the form is posting back before the data saves, and then saves the blank/default content. I've tried everything I can find on the internet to fix this. As of right now, I'm launching the dialog box on page load for testing purposes. Code Below:

Javascript:

```
function validateQuestions() {

            var q1Index = $('#<%= ddlQuest1.ClientID%>').get(0).selectedIndex;
            var q2Index = $('#<%= ddlQuest2.ClientID%>').get(0).selectedIndex;
            var q3Index = $('#<%= ddlQuest3.ClientID%>').get(0).selectedIndex;
            "<%=Q3Index%>" = q3Index;
            var label = document.getElementById('<%= _lblQuestError.ClientID%>');
            label.style.display = 'none';

            if (q1Index == q2Index || q1Index == q3Index || q2Index == q3Index) {label.style.display = 'block';}
            else {label.style.display = 'none'}
            return false;
        }

        function validateAnswers() {

            var ans1Text = $('#<%= txtAnswer1.ClientID%>').val();
            var ans2Text = $('#<%= txtAnswer2.ClientID%>').val();
            var ans3Text = $('#<%= txtAnswer3.ClientID%>').val();
            var ans1error = document.getElementById('<%= _lblAns1Error.ClientID%>');
            var ans2error = document.getElementById('<%= _lblAns2Error.ClientID%>');
            var ans3error = document.getElementById('<%= _lblAns3Error.ClientID%>');
            ans1error.style.display = 'none';
            ans2error.style.display = 'none';
            ans3error.style.display = 'none';

            if(ans1Text=""){ans1error.style.display = 'block';}                
            else if(ans2Text=""){ans2error.style.display = 'block';}
            else if(ans3Text=""){ans3error.style.display = 'block';}
            else { ans1error.style.display = 'none'; ans2error.style.display = 'none'; ans3error.style.display = 'none'}

            return false;
        }
function cancel() {
            $("#_dlgQuest").dialog('close');
            return false;
        }
function showDialog() {
            var secQuestDlg = $('#_dlgQuest').dialog({
                bgiframe: true,
                height: 350,
                width: 900,
                modal: true,
                overlay: {
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                    opacity: ".8"
                }
            });
            secQuestDlg.parent().appendTo('/html/body/form[0]');
        }
```

Button aspx: `<asp:Button ID="_dlgbtnContinue" ToolTip="Continue" runat="server" Text="Continue"
                        UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="_dlgbtnContinue_Click" CausesValidation="false"  />`

PageLoad:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlQuest3.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:validateQuestions();");
            ddlQuest1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:validateQuestions();");
            ddlQuest2.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:validateQuestions();");
            txtAnswer1.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:validateAnswers();");
            txtAnswer2.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:validateAnswers();");
            txtAnswer3.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:validateAnswers();");  
            List<String> lstQuestions = QuikDrawServiceHelper._QuikDrawClient.GetQuestions();               
            ddlCountry.Focus();
            FillQuestions();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "showDialog()", true);
            }
    }
```

Fillquestions:

```
try
            {
                foreach (string s in lstQuestions)
                {
                    if (s.Equals(Customer.Quest1Code))
                    {
                        q1 = s;
                    }
                    if (s.Equals(Customer.Quest2Code))
                    {
                        q2 = s;
                    }
                    if (s.Equals(Customer.Quest3Code))
                    {
                        q3 = s;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Complete Click Event:

```
protected void _dlgbtnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            Customer = CompanyServiceHelper._CompanyClient.GetCustomerByID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerID"].ToString()));   
            if (Session["FirstLogin"] == "Yes")
            {
                Customer.Quest1Code = ddlQuest1.SelectedValue;
                Customer.Quest1Ans = txtAnswer1.Text;
                Customer.Quest2Code = ddlQuest2.SelectedValue;
                Customer.Quest2Ans = txtAnswer2.Text;
                Customer.Quest3Code = ddlQuest3.SelectedValue;
                Customer.Quest3Ans = txtAnswer3.Text;
                CompanyServiceHelper._CompanyClient.AddQuestionsForCustomer(Customer);
                Session["FirstLogin"] = "Yes";
                Session["CustID"] = Customer.CustID;                
    }
```

I've tried linkbuttons as well, and i get the same thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i've never tried to use jqueryui dialog with WebForms.. but, try to set the values to hiddenfields before u _hide_ your dialog. if this dont work.. show us your view ! it can be a jquery problem !

Comment: I think a more complete code sample would help, its a little difficult to understand some of what is going on here.

Comment: I've updated the code, if there is anything in particular you are not understanding let me know, and I'll try to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like when you click the `dlgbtnContinue` button it is still not doing a postback, therefore you get the `!isPostBack` all over, and then resets the values. After this, the `_dlgbtnContinue_Click` event is getting triggered, saving the blank values. Maybe try to check in `!isPostBack` if also the values in the DropDown are not the default, meaning that if they are not the default values you do not want to get inside that if again. Just an idea... It would be good to have the `_dlgbtnContinue_Click` code. Good luck.

Comment: When the button is clicked, the page_load is reached, but the isPostBack value is true. However, even before the if(!isPostBack) statement is evaluated, the values for ddlQuest1.Text have already been reset. Its like even when you select different values in the dropdown, the Text, and SelectedValue properties never change...

Comment: This seems very strange. Have you tried creating a new page and doing everything again?

Comment: I ended up converting the dialog to a separate page. There was just too much going on on a single page to track down what was interfering with what.

Comment: Smart decision. Sometimes we are forced to do that. It is also more readable code, and usually better modularized.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the problem you are facing is the fact that the dialog is made "display:none" when popup disappears, and this resets all the values inside the dialog, making them not accessible on server. Despite "runat=server", form fields are not accessible on server bcz of "display:none", making you think the values are never set !!